# laravel model and table naming with underscore

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create model named `CustomDataStore` (`models/custom_data_store.php`) and it is extending Eloquent, so table is named as `custom_data_stores`, but it gives me error.

Eloquent wants table named `customdatastores`. Of course I can set manually table name, but how can I set such name automatically?

Comment: That's Laravel naming convention. If you don't like it maybe you can extend core Eloquent model with custom table-name resolving to be used with your other models. It's in `table()` method in `laravel/database/eloquent/model.php`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For it to be made automatically your model would have to be in `models/custom/data/store.php`

```
class Custom_Data_Store extends Eloquent
{

}
```

Comment: But then model will be named with underscores. But I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that laravel's eloquent can't really "see" if there are underscores on the model's filename. I'm not really sure what's happening inside (still a newbie), but this is only based on my observation..

what I did was

I have two different models, named `tblReport_date.php` and `tblReportdate.php`, both have the same codes except that they are pointed at different tables.

`tblReportdate.php` code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class tblReportdate extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    /**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'tblClients';

    ...rest of the codes...
```

`tblReport_date.php` code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class tblReportdate extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    /**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'tblReport_date';

    ...rest of the codes...
```

on the controller, I have this code

```
$db = tblReportdate::all();
return View::make('db.index')->with('db', $db);
```

the result is that it will only load `tblReportdate.php` and not `tblReport_date.php`

I tried extracting `tblReport_date.php` alone and tested it.. it always returns an error, regardless of the class name, etc..and IDK why. If someone can explain this pls comment it out.. anyways, just avoid putting underscores on filenames XD